# Can we read Spring 18 provided Custom Theme/Branding Settings in Visualforce or Apex?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, spring18, theme-branding

I would like to read the `Custom Theme/Branding` Settings opened up in Spring 18 release.

The objective is to be able to read or access the background color and background image used in the theme/branding, so that I can use the same effect in a VF page, which is not a lightning component.

This is necessary because, the iframes created for Visualforce pages has forced White background, so the theme branding background could not be seen with us re-creating the theme in VF page css.

Any way to do that? *(Not looking to create a Lightning Component for the VF page replacement)*

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities I can find:

1. `<apex:slds/>` should automatically bring in theming to Lightning style classes. I don't know however if it includes the background colour or not. https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_apex_slds_theme.htm
2. You could make a callout to the UI API to get info about the active theme. 
   https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_vf_apex_slds_theme.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_themes_active.htm

This could be done from Apex or Visualforce but it's just not as straightforward as querying.

Comment: I ll look into option 2. The other option 1 does not render background colors. The idea is to be able to use same canvas bordering like lightning component do when they r placed on a lightning page.